# What does [[Scopes]] mean in prototype?

Tags: javascript

I'm studying prototype and doing some testing, and I've decided to assign a method to the String object like this:

```
String.prototype.sel = function sel() {
    var elem = doc.querySelectorAll(this);
    if (elem.length == 1)
        return elem[0];

    return elem;
}
```

And when getting a console.log(String.prototype) and getting the method I created, I noticed that in [[Scopes]] I get 1: Global {window: Window..., what does `[[Scopes]]` mean?

Complete test:

```js
String.prototype.sel = function sel() {
    var elem = document.querySelectorAll(this);
    if (elem.length == 1)
        return elem[0];

    return elem;
}

'[btnSend]'.sel().onclick = () => {
    alert('ok')
}

console.log(String.prototype);
```

```html
<button btnSend>Send</button>
```

Comment: See [\[\[scopes\]\] and the execution context](/q/48953920/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon great!!